# PHP preg-match-all regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I would like to capture each of these in their own group with preg_match_all in PHP.

1. The chapter, section, or page
2. The number (or letter if it has one) of the specified chapter, section, or page. If there is a single space between them it should be taken into account
3. The words "and", "or"

Keeping in mind that the number of items in the string may be dynamic, the regex should work on all the examples below:

1. Ch1 and Sect2b
2. Ch 4 x blahunwantedtext and Sect 5y and Sect6 z and Ch7 or Ch8

This is what I managed to come up with so far:

```
<?php

    $str = 'Ch 1 a and Sect 2b and Pg3';
    preg_match_all ('/([a-z]+)([\s]?[0-9]+)([\s]?[a-z]*)([\s]?and*[\s]?)/is', $str, $matches);

    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Ch 1 a and 
                [1] => Sect 2b and 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Ch
                [1] => Sect
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] =>  1
                [1] =>  2
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] =>  a
                [1] => b
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [0] =>  and 
                [1] =>  and 
            )

    )
```

I'm unable to match the last portions of the string (Pg3) in my array.

The expected result should be:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Ch 1 a and 
                [1] => Sect 2b and 
                [2] => Pg3
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Ch
                [1] => Sect
                [2] => Pg
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] =>  1
                [1] =>  2
                [2] =>  3
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] =>  a
                [1] => b
                [2] => 
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [0] =>  and 
                [1] =>  and 
                [2] =>  
            )

    )
```

Comment: Add some examples to your post. Having "input -> expected result" makes figuring out your question 100x easier.

Comment: @Supericy expected result added.

Comment: @Supericy Just wondering what would I need to change to the regex to get your same result below, if there was some extra unwanted text like $str = 'Ch 1 a blahblahdontwant and Sect 2b and Pg3'?

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work `/(ch|sect|pg)\s*(\d)\s*([a-z]?\b)\s*(and|or)?/i`:

```
$str = 'Ch 1 a and Sect 2b and Pg3';
preg_match_all('/(ch|sect|pg)\s*(\d)\s*([a-z]?\b)\s*(and|or)?/i', $str, $matches);


array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Ch 1 a and' (length=10)
      1 => string 'Sect 2b and' (length=11)
      2 => string 'Pg3' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Ch' (length=2)
      1 => string 'Sect' (length=4)
      2 => string 'Pg' (length=2)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => string '3' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'a' (length=1)
      1 => string 'b' (length=1)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'and' (length=3)
      1 => string 'and' (length=3)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
```